# How to split a string into an array of characters in BIRT?

Tags: java, arrays, char, report, birt

So I'm trying to generate a report that breaks down a result of a survey. So in the survey, our users are asked to answer questions with a Leichhardt scale(Strongly Disagree - Strongly Agree). The survey will then store the answers in single characters ( A - E, with "A" being Strongly Disagree and "E" being Strongly Disagree).

The answers will then stored as a string of char with a | separating each answer, (A|B|A|C|D|E|A|E|C|D) like so in the RESULTS column.

What I'm trying to do now is to do a count of how many people answered A on the first question, or B, or C and so on. This way I can show a statistic of how many people choose each option on each answer.

Can BIRT handle this kind of task? I'm using the standalone software of BIRT v4.2.2

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using computed columns on your data set using a formular like the following to extract the single letter of your answers. You have to create one computed column per answer.

```
row["columName"].split('|')[0]
```

Then you create another computed column using the `COUNT` aggregation and filter for each letter on your computed columns where you extracted the single letters.

```
row["split0"] === 'A'
```

There you have the total count of answer `A` to the first question.

It would be easier if you store one letter column and use one column per question in the first place. But I know that you don't always have control over the format of your data source.